# How do I get the Tkinter event-listener to work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter for the GUI of a little tool I wrote with Python. Basically I just want a callback-method to be executed as soon as the contents of an entry widget have changed. This can be done with Tkinter's own variable classes (StringVar, BooleanVar, etc. - see documentation for details: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).

So I couldn't get the mechanism to work and I found a snippet online, where it works perfectly fine. Now I'm trying to figure out why my version does not work. 
As you can see in the two code examples the only difference is, that I'm using the event-listening functionality inside a class, whereas the snippet I found online only demonstrates it in a straight top-to-bottom manner.
Here's what I've already tried:

- I instantiated the Tk instance directly in the constructor of my GUI class - same behaviour.
- I inherited directly from the Tk class (instead of Frame) - same behaviour.
- I placed the callback outside of the class - same behaviour.

The only idea I have is that the problem might be scope related, which I tried to verify.

Working code snippet:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def text_changed(*args):
    print("Text changed.")

top = tk.Tk()

string_listener = StringVar()
string_listener.set("Init Text")
string_listener.trace("w", text_changed)

entry_widget = tk.Entry(top, textvariable = string_listener)
entry_widget.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Not working code snippet

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=root):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(master)

        string_listener = StringVar()
        string_listener.set("Init Text")
        string_listener.trace("w", self.text_changed_callback)

        entry_widget = tk.Entry(master, textvariable=string_listener)
        entry_widget.pack()

    def text_changed_callback(self, *args):
        print("Text changed.")

gui = GUI()
gui.mainloop()
```

Like in the working example, my code ought to print `Text changed.`, everytime a character is either deleted from or appended to the string in the extry-widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `string_listener` is a local variable, and python is destroying the variable when `__init__` finishes running. This doesn't happen in your original code since the variable is created in the global scope.

A simple solution is to save a reference as an attribute of the class:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=root):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(master)

        self.string_listener = tk.StringVar()
        self.string_listener.set("Init Text")
        self.string_listener.trace("w", self.text_changed_callback)

        entry_widget = tk.Entry(master, textvariable=self.string_listener)
        entry_widget.pack()

    def text_changed_callback(self, *args):
        print("Text changed.")

gui = GUI()
gui.mainloop()
```

note: I also changed `StringVar` to `tk.StringVar` so that I could remove the redundant wildcard import of tkinter.

Comment: Regarding the simplicity of the solution: I feel really really stupid, that I couldn't figure this out by myself. Thank you very much for your quick answer!